# How to take\move a file with specific name in python with move()

Tags: python, operating-system

for example, i have this script:

```
 for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
      print(f"we are in folder: {folder}")
      print(f"subfolder present: {subfolders}")

      for file in files: 
           if file.startswith("00"): #give me all the files that start with '00'
                print(file)

                 try:
                     shutil.move("C:\\Users\\fulvi\\Desktop\\Python_3.8\\esperimento\\00_00_01_02_0001.png", "C:\\Users\\fulvi\\Desktop\\Python_3.8\\esperimento\\altro"

                except shutil.Error:
                     print("\ngià esiste il file dentro la cartella")
```

with this script I move only one file at a time and only with the rule "start with 00"!

suppose we have .png files of this type:

00_00_01_02_0001.png
00_01_02_00_0002.png
01_01_02_02_0003.png

I want to modify the script so that it takes me, for example, all the .png files that have 00 as the third parameter. Or it takes all the .png files that have 01 as the first parameter, and so on.

I want to iterate based on the specific name of the .png file, but not the full name of the file!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all your files follow the same naming format, I would advise you to use string slicing. This way you can check the string character and do what you like with it.

See [here](https://www.journaldev.com/23584/python-slice-string) to learn more on string slicing.

Once you apply this you should have something like:

```py
 for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
      print(f"we are in folder: {folder}")
      print(f"subfolder present: {subfolders}")

      for file in files: 
           if file[0:2]=="01": #this would check the first parameter
                print(file)

                 try:
                     shutil.move("C:\\Users\\fulvi\\Desktop\\Python_3.8\\esperimento\\00_00_01_02_0001.png", "C:\\Users\\fulvi\\Desktop\\Python_3.8\\esperimento\\altro"

                except shutil.Error:
                     print("\ngià esiste il file dentro la cartella")
           elif file[6:8] == "00":#this would check the thrid parameter
                print(file)

                 try:
                     shutil.move("C:\\Users\\fulvi\\Desktop\\Python_3.8\\esperimento\\00_00_01_02_0001.png", "C:\\Users\\fulvi\\Desktop\\Python_3.8\\esperimento\\altro"

                except shutil.Error:
                     print("\ngià esiste il file dentro la cartella")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I figured you had to use string slices but I didn't know how to do it ...

 but now I don't understand how to modify the move() function. This takes the path and file name as parameters.. so i can't write the name of the .png file because it only takes one at a time!

I should do: 
                     shutil.move("C:\\Users\\fulvi\\Desktop\\Python_3.8\\esperimento\\ **file** ", "C:\\Users\\fulvi\\Desktop\\Python_3.8\\esperimento\\altro"

obviously gives me error because I have to specify the exact name of the .png file